# Service with LocationManager check for permission

Tags: android, service, permissions, locationmanager, android-6.0-marshmallow

I need to send the location to the server.
This is on my service class:

lm.requestLocationUpdates(PROVIDER, 600000, 0, myLocationListener);

But i dont know how to call this because this need to check for permissions.

Suggest please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking for permissions does not change, just because you are using a service. Call `checkSelfPermission()` on the service itself.

What *is* different is that you cannot *ask the user for permission* from a service.

The best solution to cover most use cases is to *also* check the permission in your activity/fragment before you start (or bind to) the service, and ask the user for permission if you do not have it.

Alternatively, have your service display a `Notification` that leads to an activity where you can ask the user for permission. The activity would need to re-request the service to do its work at that point, so the service knows that it is safe to call `requestLocationUpdates()`.

Comment: suppose user had granted all permissions and then revoked permission from Settings-App Info. How to handle this in service?

Comment: @Sandeep: Your process should be terminated when the user revokes permission. If your service restarts before you hae a chance to request permission, have your service display a `Notification` that leads to an activity where you can ask the user for permission. The activity would need to re-request the service to do its work at that point.

Comment: in case of activity i can check and prompt permission dialog, but in service how can use this?

Comment: @Sandeep: As I have written twice, and will now write again in boldface, **have your service display a `Notification` that leads to an activity where you can ask the user for permission**. A `Service` itself *cannot* request a permission from the user. You have to use an `Activity` for that. So, display a `Notification`, so when the user is ready, the user can click on that `Notification` and you can ask for permission.